# .Replace(String,String) VB function not works

Tags: vb.net, replace

I need to replace the end of a pathfile in VB. So I try this code :

```
Private Function getfiledata(ByVal fichier As String) As String
  Dim fileReader As String
  Dim FichierFinal As String
  MsgBox(fichier)
  FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("E002.pfx","_E002.pem")
  FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("X002.pfx","_X002.pem")
  FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("A005.pfx","_A005.pem")
  MsgBox(FichierFinal)
  fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FichierFinal)
  Return fileReader
End Function
```

The first MsgBox function return me the following result :

> C:/Users/Bruno/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2010/Projects/SerEbics/SerEbics/bin/Debug/Certificats/512250X002.pfx

But the second return me the same path :

> C:/Users/Bruno/Documents/Visual Studio2010/Projects/SerEbics/SerEbics/bin/Debug/Certificats/512250X002.pfx

So I need this result :

> C:/Users/Bruno/Documents/Visual Studio2010/Projects/SerEbics/SerEbics/bin/Debug/Certificats/512250_X002.pem

Thank you in advance !

Thomas

Comment: Your second `Replace` makes the change you want, but the third one overwrites the result of the second. I think you intended the second and third `Replace` statements to be `FichierFinal = FichierFinal.Replace("X002.pfx","_X002.pem")` and `FichierFinal = FichierFinal.Replace("A005.pfx","_A005.pem")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing what you think. At each new line you cancelled the previous one 
and defining `FichierFinal` to a new value.

This will works (plus no need to do this in 3 lines):

```
FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("E002.pfx","_E002.pem").Replace("X002.pfx","_X002.pem").Replace("A005.pfx","_A005.pem")
```

Answer (score 3):

The three lines in a row using teh Replace function are not doing quite what you think. Each time, they are setting `FichierFinal` to something new. So they are not building on each other. Try replacing them with this:

```
FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("E002.pfx","_E002.pem")
FichierFinal = FichierFinal.Replace("X002.pfx","_X002.pem")
FichierFinal = FichierFinal.Replace("A005.pfx","_A005.pem")
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your last Replace restore the original name in the variable `FichierFinal`. You should execute your replaces only if the file ends with one of the expected strings.

```
If fichier.EndsWith("E002.pfx") Then
   FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("E002.pfx","_E002.pem")
Else if fichier.EndsWith("X002.pfx") Then
   FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("X002.pfx","_X002.pem")
Else if fichier.EndsWith("A005.pfx") Then
   FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("A005.pfx","_A005.pem")
End If
```

In this way you execute the Replace just one time and not three times. Remember that every time you call Replace a new string is allocated and returned and depending on the context of your calls this could have effects on the performances of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code u wrong replace:

```
Private Function getfiledata(ByVal fichier As String) As String
  Dim fileReader As String
  Dim FichierFinal As String
  MsgBox(fichier)
  FichierFinal = fichier.Replace("E002.pfx","_E002.pem")
  FichierFinal = FichierFinal.Replace("X002.pfx","_X002.pem")
  FichierFinal = FichierFinal.Replace("A005.pfx","_A005.pem")
  MsgBox(FichierFinal)
  fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FichierFinal)
  Return fileReader
End Function
```